# Mysql Date from Null to 00-00-0000

Tags: php, mysql, date, null

Well I have a weird problem with MySQL.

I have a table like this :

```
# table_name #
==============
ID | DATE | RESULT_DATE
```

When I do

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

the output show me the table_name.RESULT_DATE as NULL or if there is a date, it show me the date.

BUT, when I do something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2017-05-03' AND '2017-05-08'
```

the output show me the table_name.RESULT_DATE as 00-00-0000 for **ALL** the elements, if they were NULL or if they had a Date element...

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: 2017 minus 5 minus 3 equals 2009

Comment: Well no, this is not the same question ... In the question you linked it's talking about which quotes should be use, in my question I just want to know why I obtain that result and it's not a problem of Quotes, I tried every quotes possible and get the same result!

Comment: Well I guess you asked the wrong question then. I'll reopen...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hmmm I read the link, but I didn't find my answer... Sorry If I asked the wrong question, to make it easier, when I select without WHERE I have my **RESULT_DATE** column with _NULL_ or _dates_, but when I Select with a WHERE statement, my **RESULT_DATE** column is full of _00-00-0000_ date (and this is also strange because it doesn't respect the date format `YYYY-MM-DD`)... It's the first time I get something like this...

Comment: I guess you didn't really read the link. Even if I say so myself, the accepted answer is entirely self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the quotes around the dates

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2017-05-03' AND '2017-05-08'
                      here------------------^----------^-----^----------^
```

Comment: I tried with the Quotes, single quote, doble quotes... but didn't work, same result! :/